# Validation for textbox in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I need your help. I am working with MVC3-Razor application. I need to validate a textbox on View (.cshtml file) in such a way that, the starting 2 characters must be "PR" and 4th character must be "2". This is the requirement. How would i achieve this functionality? Any suggestions, it would be great help. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Using Regular expressions!

Comment: Thanks ckv 4 for quick response. I am very much to MVC3. Can you please help me that how will i achieve this? I guess we can use regular expression for a range of characters in a specified format.

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302822/client-side-regex-validation-based-on-regular-expression-attribute-fails

Comment: Duplicate ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825841/how-to-validate-textbox-in-mvc3-that-must-contain-string-started-with-characters)..
Regex is a great way! If only I knew how they work

Comment: Thanks Yaseen. Can you please help me out for my requirement that first 2 characters must be "PR" and 4th should be "2"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Model**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
      public int ID { get; set; }

      [RegularExpression(@"^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]2([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Name.")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DYmanicControllerPage", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
{ 
      <div>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
      </div>
}
```